# Finding in between time in a list of times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
    userid | eventid | description |    date     | starttime | endtime
    1        1         Event 1       2016-02-02     09:30:00  11:00:00
    1        2         Event 2       2016-02-02     13:30:00  15:00:00
    1        3         Event 3       2016-02-02     17:30:00  21:00:00
    2        4         Event 4       2016-02-03     13:00:00  14:00:00
    2        5         Event 5       2016-02-03     15:00:00  16:00:00
```

I need to find what is the sum of time between the events on the same day by the user.

Like this:

```
   userid |  timeBetween
   1          05:00:00
   2          01:00:00
```

I should also assume that there may be overlapping times for example event1 starts at 11:00 ends 13:00 and event2 starts 12:00 and ends 14:00 by the same user on the same day. These cases are rare and I believe returning 00:00 here is the appropriate answer.

I solved a similar problem, finding the sum of the length of all events per day.

```
SELECT *, 
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`endtime`,`starttime`)))) as sumtime
FROM `events`
group by userid, date
order by sumtime desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`userid` int, `eventid` int, `description` varchar(7), `date` date, `starttime` time, `endtime` time)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`userid`, `eventid`, `description`, `date`, `starttime`, `endtime`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Event 1', '2016-02-02', '09:30:00', '11:00:00'),
    (1, 2, 'Event 2', '2016-02-02', '13:30:00', '15:00:00'),
    (1, 3, 'Event 3', '2016-02-02', '17:30:00', '21:00:00'),
    (2, 4, 'Event 4', '2016-02-03', '13:00:00', '14:00:00'),
    (2, 5, 'Event 5', '2016-02-03', '15:00:00', '16:00:00')
;
```

this query

```
SELECT userid, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(diff))) AS time_between
FROM (

    SELECT
    TIMEDIFF(starttime, COALESCE(IF(userid != @prev_userid, NULL, @prev_endtime), starttime)) AS diff,
    @prev_endtime := endtime,
    @prev_userid := userid AS userid
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @prev_endtime := NULL, @prev_userid := NULL) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY userid

) sq
GROUP BY userid;
```

will return

```
+--------+--------------+
| userid | time_between |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | 05:00:00     |
|      2 | 01:00:00     |
+--------+--------------+
```

Explanation:

In this part

```
, (SELECT @prev_endtime := NULL, @prev_userid := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY userid
```

we initialize our variables. The `ORDER BY` is very important, since there's no order in a relational database unless you specify it. It is so important, because the `SELECT` clause processes the rows in this order.

In the `SELECT` clause the order is also very important. Here

```
@prev_endtime := endtime,
@prev_userid := userid AS userid
```

we assign the values of the current row to the variables. Since this happens after this line

```
TIMEDIFF(starttime, COALESCE(IF(userid != @prev_userid, NULL, @prev_endtime), starttime)) AS diff,
```

the variables still hold the values of the previous row in the `timediff()` function. Therefore we also have to use `COALESCE()`, because in the very first row and when the userid changes, there is no value to calculate the diff from. To get a diff of 0 there, `COALESCE()` exchanges the `NULL` value with the starttime.

The last part is obviously to simply sum the seconds of the "between times".

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can get the `timeBetween` value in `SECONDS`

```
SELECT 
firsttable.userid,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(secondtable.starttime) - TIME_TO_SEC(firsttable.endtime))) timeBetween
FROM 
(
        SELECT 
        *,
        IF(@prev = userid, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1, @rn1 := 1) rank,
        @prev := userid
        FROM eventtable,(SELECT @prev := 0,@rn1 := 1) var
        ORDER BY userid,starttime DESC
) firsttable
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT 
        *,
        IF(@prev2 = userid, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1, @rn2 := 1) rank,
        @prev2 := userid
        FROM eventtable,(SELECT @prev2 := 0,@rn2 := 1) var
        ORDER BY userid,endtime DESC
) secondTable

ON firsttable.userid = secondtable.userid AND firsttable.rank = secondtable.rank + 1 AND 
   firsttable.date = secondtable.date
GROUP BY firsttable.userid;
```

---

**TEST:**

Unable to add a **fiddle**.

So here's test data with schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `eventtable`;
CREATE TABLE `eventtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `starttime` time NOT NULL,
  `endtime` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
INSERT INTO `eventtable` VALUES ('1', '1', '1', 'Event 1', '2016-02-02', '09:30:00', '11:00:00');
INSERT INTO `eventtable` VALUES ('2', '1', '2', 'Event 2', '2016-02-02', '13:30:00', '15:00:00');
INSERT INTO `eventtable` VALUES ('3', '1', '3', 'Event 3', '2016-02-02', '17:30:00', '21:00:00');
INSERT INTO `eventtable` VALUES ('4', '2', '4', 'Event 4', '2016-02-03', '13:00:00', '14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `eventtable` VALUES ('5', '2', '5', 'Event 5', '2016-02-03', '15:00:00', '16:00:00');
```

**Result:**

Executing the above query on the given test data you will get output like below:

```
userid    timeBetween
1          05:00:00
2          01:00:00
```

**Note:** 
For overlapping events the above query will give you negative `timeBetween` value.

You can replace the the `SEC_TO_TIME...`line by the following:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(IF(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(secondtable.starttime) - TIME_TO_SEC(firsttable.endtime)) < 0, 0,SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(secondtable.starttime) - TIME_TO_SEC(firsttable.endtime)))) timeBetween
```

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary, and when you don't explain such complicated answers, you might as well spare yourself the trouble.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for not being able to remove the complexity right now. Later I can optimize the query. Just focused on the functional part. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the TIMEDIFF of the MIN(starttime) and MAX(endtime) for each user/day and then subtract the sum of events as calculated earlier, this will give you the times in between.

Comment: I have tried this method and it doesn't work properly, especially when there are overlaps.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the overlaps although, mathematically speaking, it would be correct since the gap between 1pm and noon is -1 hour! Not very helpful in a practical setting, though. You'd have to subtract (ie add) all of the negative values for that day.

Comment: Yes, but I sill believe this is a good answer for those looking for a simple way to get results asap.

Answer (score -1):

try this on

`select TIMEDIFF('start_time','end_time') from your table`

hope this one help you